# Resources to study the Abhidharma in the East/North Asian schools of Buddhism (e,g, Mahayana, Tibetan, Yogacara, Dharmaguptaka, etc.)

Tags: reference-request, mahayana, tibetan-buddhism, abhidhamma, yogacara

What are good resources and references (ideally online) to learn Abhidharma from East and North Asian (Mahayana, Tibetan, Yogacara, Asaṅga, Vasubandhu, Dharmaguptaka, etc.) schools of Buddhism.

*NB: I am aware of BPU BPhil 3rd Year Lecture Notes. So I am looking for resource other than this.*

Comment: Broke it down from school to narrow it down as not every one person may have expertise in both schools. E.g. instead of asking what all abrahamic religions say about X breaking it down as What Christians have to say about X and What Muslims have to say about X and What Jews have to say about X.

Comment: There is an accepted answer below, but do not consider the question closed. If anybody finds anything else please post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- > The Tattvasiddhi Śāstra, also called the Satyasiddhi Śāstra, is an extant abhidharma text written by Harivarman, a 4th-century monk from central India. Harivarman is often thought to come from the Bahuśrutīya school, but the Tattvasiddhi contains teachings more similar to those of the Sautrāntika Sarvāstivādins. This abhidharma is now contained in the Chinese Buddhist canon in sixteen fascicles (Taishō Tripiṭaka 1646). Paramārtha cites this abhidharma text as containing a combination of Hīnayāna and Mahāyāna doctrines, and Joseph Walser agrees that this assessment is correct. Ian Charles Harris also characterizes the text as a synthesis of Hīnayāna and Mahāyāna, and notes that its doctrines are very close to those in Mādhyamaka and Yogācāra works. <sub>(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bahu%C5%9Brut%C4%ABya))</sub>

  A PDF scan is available [here at Scribd.com](http://www.scribd.com/mobile/doc/104775752/Satyasiddhisastra-of-Harivarman)
- > The Abhidharmakośakārikā or Verses on the Treasury of Abhidharma is a key text on the Abhidharma written in Sanskrit verse by Vasubandhu in the 4th or 5th century. It summarizes the Sarvāstivādin tenets in eight chapters with a total of around 600 verses. The text was widely respected and used by schools of Buddhism in India, Tibet and East Asia.
  >
  > Vasubandhu wrote a commentary to this work called the Abhidharmakośabhāsya. In it, he critiques the interpretations of the Sarvāstivādins, Vaibhāṣikas and others of the tenets he presented in his previous work from a Sautrāntika perspective. This commentary includes an additional chapter in prose refuting the idea of the "person" (pudgala) favoured by some Buddhists of the Pudgalavada school. However, later Sarvāstivādin master Samghabhadra considered that he misrepresented their school in the process, and at this point designated Vasubandhu as a Sautrāntika - upholder of the sutras. <sub>(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhidharmako%C5%9Bak%C4%81rik%C4%81))</sub>

  PDF scan of the [80-pages summary by Stefan Anacker for Encyclopedia of Indian Philosophies](http://lirs.ru/lib/kosa/Abhidharmakosa_bhasya_sum,Anacker,1999,EoIP.pdf)

  PDF scans of complete Abhidharmakośa**bhāsya**: [vol 1](http://lirs.ru/lib/kosa/Abhidharmakosabhasyam,vol_1,Vasubandhu,Poussin,Pruden,1991.pdf), [vol 2](http://lirs.ru/lib/kosa/Abhidharmakosabhasyam,vol_2,Vasubandhu,Poussin,Pruden,1991.pdf), [vol 3](http://lirs.ru/lib/kosa/Abhidharmakosabhasyam,vol_3,Vasubandhu,Poussin,Pruden,1991.pdf), [vol 4](http://lirs.ru/lib/kosa/Abhidharmakosabhasyam,vol_4,Vasubandhu,Poussin,Pruden,1991.pdf)

  Hard copy of the bhāsya is [available for purchase on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/8120836073)
  Hard copy of the [commentary by 9th Karmapa on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1934608254)

  Study materials for Abhidharmakośa**kārikā** by [Korin Pokorny](http://sfzc.aawsom.net/ggf/display.asp?catid=3&pageid=1412):

  - [Historical overview and introduction](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/05/introductory-materials.pdf)
  - Chapter 1. [Text](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-1-dhatu1.pdf). [Explanations](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-1-dhatu.pdf).
  - Chapter 2. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-2-indriya1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-2-indriya.pdf).
  - Chapter 3. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-3-loka1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-3-loka.pdf).
  - Chapter 4. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-4-karma1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-4-karma.pdf).
  - Chapter 5. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-5-anusaya1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-5-anusaya.pdf).
  - Chapter 6. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-6-marga-pudgala1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-6-marga-pudgala.pdf).
  - Chapter 7. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-7-jnana1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-7-jnana.pdf).
  - Chapter 8. [Text](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-8-samapatti1.pdf). [Explanations](http://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-8-samapatti.pdf).
  - Chapter 9. [Text](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-9-pudgala-viniscaya1.pdf). [Explanations](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/07/chapter-9-pudgala-viniscaya.pdf).
  - [Everything in one PDF](https://abhidharmakosa.files.wordpress.com/2010/09/kosa-study-materials.pdf)
- > Abhidharma-samuccaya (Compendium of Abhidharma) is a Buddhist text composed by Asanga. Abhidharma-samuccaya is a complete and systematic account of the Abhidharma. <sub>(from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abhidharma-samuccaya))</sub>

  [An edited transcript of a series of lectures given by the Venerable Traleg Kyabgon, Rinpoche at Kagyu E-Vam Buddhist Institute (KEBI) from July to October, 1983](http://lirs.ru/lib/Abhidharmasamuccaya,Traleg,1998.pdf)

  PDF scan of [complete Abhidharma-samuccaya](http://lirs.ru/lib/Abhidharmasamuccaya,Asanga,Rahula,1971,Boin-Webb,2001.pdf)

  Hard copy is [available for purchase on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0895819414).

Comment: Just wondering if there is a more clean copy of Tattvasiddhi Śāstra which includes the whole text?